# Incorrect Pub Key from Wallet Emulator

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, cabal, repl

I am getting incorrect pubkeys by running `mockWalletPaymentPubKey $ knownWallet 1` and `mockWalletPaymentPubKey $ knownWallet 2` (from here https://youtu.be/ae7U_yKIQ0Y?t=1390).

I checked that

- I am in the correct directory
- I imported the wallet emulator using `import Wallet.Emulator`
- and the `cabal build` command ran successfully.

On restarting the repl, I get the same incorrect wallet pub keys.

Note: I was able to get the correct pub keys by looking at the transactions in the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mockWalletPaymentPubKey` gives you the public key for a wallet.

For `Vesting.hs`, you need to use the public key **hash**.

Try `mockWalletPaymentPubKeyHash $ knownWallet 1` instead.